# Packaging a set of executable jars with conda

Tags: java, anaconda, executable-jar, anaconda3

I'm quite new to anaconda/conda packaging.

I'd like to package a software suite that generate many **executable jars**.

As far as I understand (*and may be I'm wrong*) the package description is downloaded as an archive.tar.bz2 from https://anaconda.org/ and contains everything that is needed to **compile the code on the client side**.

Therefore, those *.tar.bz2 **should not** contain the executable jar (?). However, if I look at https://anaconda.org/bioconda/picard/files the tar.bz2 files seem to contains the executable jar `picard.jar` (?)

So, what is the right place to put the jars after `conda-build` archive without including the executable jars in the archive.tar.bz2 ?

Note:

my build.sh so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u

ACTIVATE_DIR=$PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d
DEACTIVATE_DIR=$PREFIX/etc/conda/deactivate.d
## will create/drop a variable MY_TOOL_BASE_DIR
cp -v $RECIPE_DIR/activate.sh $ACTIVATE_DIR/mytool-activate.sh
cp -v $RECIPE_DIR/deactivate.sh $DEACTIVATE_DIR/mytool-deactivate.sh

mkdir -p $PREFIX/dist
./gradlew tool1 tool2 tool3 toolN
# with PREFIX, the executable jars are included in the archive
mv -v dist/*.jar $PREFIX/dist/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer from https://gitter.im/bioconda/Lobby?at=5e3be527f301780b836c4323

> Conda packages (99% of the time) contain compiled version of software, it's the whole of it to not have to compile stuff on users' computers.